# Letting through right click (only), works on image but not iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, mouseevent

Trying to figure out how to get this script working with vimeo embeds.
Seems to work alright with images (tried in FF, Chrome and Safari in OS X). However the vimeo embed just won't bring up the contextual menu.

Ideas how to solve?

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/eliraz/1)

```
$('.container').mousedown(function(e){
    if ( e.which == 3 ){
        var overlay = $(this).find('.overlay');
        overlay.hide();
        setTimeout(function() {
          overlay.show();         
        }, 50);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is working for me.  The red overlay disappears for a fraction of a second on both containers.

Comment: @Danwilliger But is the contextual menu shown?